# XamlParseException after deploying WPF project

Tags: wpf, deployment, xamlparseexception

I have been trying to deploy my WPF app, I created a Setup Project using the Setup Wizard.The only Project Output I added was Primary. After building this and installing the program, as soon as i click the exe on my desktop i get a pop up that says "'My Program' has stopped working", so  i click Debug the Program and i see

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '9'.

This exception does not point me in any direction as to what to fix. there is no 'connectionId' anywhere in my app.

I had previously ran into an XAMLParseException because of my NotifyIcon for my system tray, but this was fixed by adding the icon to the path of my exe. I thought this may be the problem so i added the icon to my Setup Project, along with all the other Project Outputs. Still Not Working.

I know this is a vague error but any help at all would be appreciated, my app won't run at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is normally caused by not having all dependencies copied to the output. As you say the error message is not very helpful, but I would check that your application has all the necessary dependencies available to resolve the parsed types.

Normally it is enough to set Copy Local to true for referenced assemblies, but I've experienced some cases where references themselves reference assemblies, so it can be necessary to explicitly add those references as well.

**Update:**

**Important addition by @BENN1TH.**

**If you want to see what an assembly is necessary:**

Was getting the same type of issue once i had published and installed my project (was working fine in debug VS2013 Desktop, no errors etc) but used the advice in from http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx and wham! installed project was working..

```
try

{
  InitializeComponent();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  // Log error (including InnerExceptions!)
  // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: i made sure i included all the dlls i have referenced in my assembly. how can i tell which other ones i might need?

Comment: ohh it is working now. i needed the references and also to make sure that my icon was in the Application's Folder. i think part of my problem was i added the icon into the build along with the project outputs. i needed to build, install, then add the icon after the fact. anyway, thank so much for the help

Comment: When I got this exception, I was able to go into the debugger and look at the InnerException to see which dll was missing.

Answer (score 9):

Cleaning and Rebuilding the solution might help!

Comment: Rebuilding worked for me, and without this answer I may not have thought of it, so thanks

Comment: I had the same problem after adding animation trigger from blend. deleting the bin and obj then rebuild, solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with a WPF solution in VS2010. The solution contained a simple dll and a test project (set to startup) for testing the dll. My dll was set to x86 and my test project was set to x64. When I changed the test project to x86 the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you get this exception in the debugger check the InnerException member of the exception. It might give you a hint about which assembly that is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same type of issue once i had published and installed my project (was working fine in debug VS2013 Desktop, no errors etc) but used the advice in from http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx and wham! installed project was working..

```
try

{
  InitializeComponent();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  // Log error (including InnerExceptions!)
  // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a good 4 hours trying to figure this out. Mine ended up being nothing to do with the xaml! Turned out it was a minor error in the code behind on MainWindow initialize.

If all else fails, check there

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning and rebuilding the project was not effective for me.

You can try to delete bin Directory then rebuild, I solved my problem by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this problem. This problem occurs due to Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll please download dll and add reference.

Comment: @HansZ, maybe he is trying to answer the question, but in a cryptic way.

Comment: @Hans Z, this could be an answer because a DLL problem is a common error for Microsoft.

Comment: agreed, removed the comment

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when working with multiple dlls running inside an application and those dlls have differing versions of the same dependency loaded.

We normally merge the dlls during our release build to prevent this issue, but we see it if we are testing more then one set of unmerged dlls during development cycle.

The solution it to only test one set of unmerged dlls, using merged release versions for the other dlls that are not being tested, or to ensure that the dependent dll is the same version for both sets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing **Sign the assembly**, here :

[image]