# xamlParseException on window launch

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

I get the following error when I show this window from another window in my application:

> XamlParseException occurred 'Set connectionId threw an exception.'
>   Line number '4' and line position '25'.

With an inner exception of:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabControl'
>   to type 'WpfApplication1.Window1'."}

My xaml code is as follows:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="482" Width="603" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="402" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="569" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid></Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem2" Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid Height="374" Width="563">
                <ListView Height="317" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="IP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerIP}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Host Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HostName}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="MAC" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MAC}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Avg. Ping Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem3" Name="tabItem3">
            <Grid Height="307" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,408,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Next" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,12,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
    <Button Content="Back" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,408,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Rectangle Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,40,0,0" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="453" />
    <ProgressBar Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,408,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Button Content="Remove" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="486,363,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="False" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,363,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,363,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="To" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,360,421,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Search" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,363,0,0" Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button5_Click" />
</Grid>
```

If you need my C# code to figure out this problem I can Email it to you, but it is against company policy to put that code on the web (and <strike>I enjoy my job...</strike> I dont want to get fired)

Please keep in mind that I normaly develop in VB.net, and C#.net is very new to me, so if you could please detail your explanations for a beginner that would be appreciated.

---

c#.net
vs2010
Windows Vista x64
Intel Core 2 Quad

Comment: The ugliness of that code points towards the use of a GUI-designer, using a `Grid` without creating rows and columns is quite pointless...

Comment: In VB you never have to write this kind of code, so please excuse the ugglieness... This is a mish-mash of blogCode vs2010 autogen code.

Comment: I'd recommend hand-coding, otherwise you'll probably end up with something unreadable and unmaintainable sooner or later.

Comment: What happens if you remove `Loaded="Window_Loaded"`?

Comment: Luks to me like a code behind error than XAML parser error. Window_Loaded looks like the culprit to me.

Comment: @Reid, you have to write this kind of code in VB too, if you use WPF.

Answer (score 10):

Try Rebuilding the complete solution from Solution Explorer.

Comment: Why downvoted? A complete rebuild solved it for me.

Comment: Indeed, right click the project and rebuild solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Since the outer exception mentions the `connectionid` the invalid cast has to be done in a automatically generated code file that accompanies the window and is found in the `obj` folder of the project. It should be called `Window1.g.cs`.

Look at the `Connect` method, there should be a case with `#line 4 ...` where it tries to attach the `Window.Loaded` event, maybe you can see why it tries to cast the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

I received a similarly titled error and it was because the project was configured to build in AnyCPU, but a dependent assembly was set as x86. Changing the project to x86 resolved this issue.

Comment: Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615597/xamlparseexception-after-deploying-wpf-project as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is likly due to some missing ddl. check the inner exception and you will have a clue about the missing dll.