# I can't execute a project on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, kinect

I am doing this Robosapien Kinect project in C# ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKpO5F8LsCk ) and I zipped the code source form here https://github.com/fatihboy/Robosapien and I don't know why that when I open the KinectRopsapien project with Visual Studio 2012 and I run and debug the MainWindow.xaml.cs window, the window that should show what the Kinect is filming is not opening and there is blue bar on the bottom saying "Ready". I have Kinect for Windows SDK 1.7 installed on my computer. On the first image is a message that appears twice while the code is being debugged in which I click "Continue" (which I think is to finish debugging and I think there is no problem to continue) and the second image is what appears after the code is debugged where you can see the blue bar below saying "Ready" and when the window of what the Kinect is filming should appear, in which I have the Kinect and USB Uirt connected to my computer. So I would like to know why there is no window opening after I run the code? Thank you for your attention

img850.imageshack.us/img850/7566/13285409.png - First image img547.imageshack.us/img547/1449/31396912.png - Second image

Comment: Do you have the supported version of the Kinect SDK installed on your system.

Comment: Yes I have the Kinect for Windows SDK 1.7 installed, it's drivers appear on the device manager when I connect the Kinect to the computer

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the problem itself.

Comment: In this first image is a message that appears twice while the code is being debugged in which I click "Continue" (which I think is to finish debugging and I think there is no problem to continue)
and the second image is what appears after the code is debugged where you can see the blue bar below saying "Ready" and when the window of what the Kinect is filming should appear.



http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/7566/13285409.png - First image

http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/1449/31396912.png - Second image

Answer (score 0):

Identical problem... [XamlParseException after deploying WPF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615597/xamlparseexception-after-deploying-wpf-project)

In this case the project was clean re-built...

However, I do think it might be deeper than that. Try: http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx that at least then should give you more concrete information.

Answer (score 0):

This program worked great for me in VS 2010 running .Net Framework 4.0 and debug as x86.

I can see your Debug is set as Any CPU in your screenshot. Make sure it is set as x86.