# Why am I getting a XamlParseException when using my NuGet package from another project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm writing a WinRT-based library in C# ([here's](https://github.com/jamesqo/Sirloin) the source code) where I expose a custom XAML control called `AppView`. When I compile the library locally and use it from my [sample app](https://github.com/jamesqo/Sirloin/tree/master/samples/Sirloin.Example), it seems to be working fine. However, if I upload it to NuGet and use it like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    new AppView();

    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

then I get a `XamlParseException` when the constructor is called. I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615597/xamlparseexception-after-deploying-wpf-project#comment11556887_4615629) of breaking in the debugger when it was thrown, but unfortunately it just says 'XAML parsing failed.' and the `InnerException` is null.

These problems have been happening ever since I factored out part of my library into another DLL. So far, I have tried:

- including the other DLL ([commit](https://github.com/jamesqo/Sirloin/commit/d891a613429e83d88516f474eb5edc88dfd0911f))
- including everything in the `Release` directory ([commit](https://github.com/jamesqo/Sirloin/commit/c8dc1d5cee56d7a7600e8a1dd382a373080bd391))
- publishing the other DLL as a separate NuGet package

If you're interested in repro-ing this for yourself, [here's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sirloin/2.5.0) the link to the package on NuGet.

---

**edit:** Added the [wpf] tag since that platform is also closely related to XAML.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it looks like I've answered my own question! Following the excellent steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611883/4077294) worked for me. All I had to do was go into my project's **Properties** > **Build** and check **Generate library layout**. I then updated my nuspec file to just include everything in the output directory, like so:

```
<file src="bin\Release\**" target="lib\.NETCore50" />
```

After that, everything worked perfectly.